# Getting TextInput while also preventing KeyDown and Keyup events from propagating to parent controls

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I have a custom WPF control that wants to handle both key down and up events as well as text input. For instance, if the user hits Home on the keyboard, I want to handle that in my custom control and prevent it from bubbling up to other controls.

Now, I can achieve this by handling the key down and up events in my custom control and setting `KeyEventArgs.Handled` to `true`. However, this has the unfortunate side effect that text input events then aren't getting generated.

How do I handle both key down and key up events as well as text input without letting the events propagate to parent controls (pretty much how a textbox control does)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the KeyEventArgs.Handled to true only for keys you are interested in handling, such as Home key from your example and allow the rest to bubble through.

Comment: I'm interested in all keys. I'm feeding the keyboard input to another library, which needs both down, up, and character input. I basically want to function like a textbox (i.e. allow Home to be pressed without propagating, while also getting character input), but I'm unclear on how they trap all these events.